# NullPointerException : Initialization of bean failed

Tags: grails, spring-security, nullpointerexception, saml-2.0, grails-plugin

I am getting following error when I execute grails run-app, I am trying to run my grails application locally but unable to do so

Following is the error from Stacktrace

### Stacktrace

```
2017-01-25T06:01:32.640+05:00 uptime="38155", level="ERROR", class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener", thread="localhost-startStop-1:", message="Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'samlIDPDiscovery': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setSamlEntryPoint' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'samlEntryPoint': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContextProvider' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'contextProvider': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'metadataResolver' while setting bean property 'metadataResolver'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metadataResolver': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextProvider': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'metadataResolver' while setting bean property 'metadataResolver'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metadataResolver': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'samlEntryPoint': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContextProvider' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'contextProvider': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'metadataResolver' while setting bean property 'metadataResolver'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metadataResolver': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextProvider': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'metadataResolver' while setting bean property 'metadataResolver'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metadataResolver': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException"
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'samlIDPDiscovery': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setSamlEntryPoint' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'samlEntryPoint': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContextProvider' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'contextProvider': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'metadataResolver' while setting bean property 'metadataResolver'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metadataResolver': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextProvider': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'metadataResolver' while setting bean property 'metadataResolver'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metadataResolver': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'samlEntryPoint': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContextProvider' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'contextProvider': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'metadataResolver' while setting bean property 'metadataResolver'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metadataResolver': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextProvider': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'metadataResolver' while setting bean property 'metadataResolver'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metadataResolver': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'samlEntryPoint': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContextProvider' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'contextProvider': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'metadataResolver' while setting bean property 'metadataResolver'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metadataResolver': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextProvider': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'metadataResolver' while setting bean property 'metadataResolver'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metadataResolver': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextProvider': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'metadataResolver' while setting bean property 'metadataResolver'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metadataResolver': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metadataResolver': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    ... 4 more
```

### Config.groovy

```
security {
    saml {
        userAttributeMappings = ['firstName': 'FirstName', 'lastName': 'LastName', 'email': 'EmailAddress']
        userGroupToRoleMapping = [:]
        active = true
        afterLoginUrl = '/'
        afterLogoutUrl = '/'
        loginFormUrl = '/saml/login'
        userGroupAttribute = "memberOf"
        responseSkew = 60
        idpSelectionPath = '/'
        autoCreate {
            active =  true
            key = 'username'
            assignAuthorities = true
        }
        metadata {
            defaultIdp = 'http://idp.ssocircle.com'
            url = '/saml/metadata'
            //default idp info
            idp{
                file = 'security/idp.xml'
                alias = 'http://idp.ssocircle.com'
            }
            sp {
                file = 'security/sp.xml'
                alias = 'jbilling' 
                defaults{
                    local = true
                    alias = 'jbilling'
                    signingKey = 'ping'
                    encryptionKey = 'ping'
                    tlsKey = 'ping'
                    requireArtifactResolveSigned = false
                    requireLogoutRequestSigned = false
                    requireLogoutResponseSigned = false
                    idpDiscoveryEnabled = true
                }
            }
        }
        keyManager {
            storeFile = 'classpath:security/keystore.jks'
            storePass = 'nalle123'
            passwords = [ ping: 'ping123' ]
            defaultKey = 'ping'
        }
    }
}
```

### resources.groovy

```
    def conf = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig
    if (!conf || !conf.active) { return }

    SpringSecurityUtils.loadSecondaryConfig 'SamlSecurityConfig'
    conf = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig
    if (!conf.saml.active) { return }


    println 'Configuring Spring Security SAML ...'

    //Due to Spring DSL limitations, need to import these beans as XML definitions
    def beansFile = "classpath:security/springSecuritySamlBeans.xml"
    delegate.importBeans beansFile

    xmlns context:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    context.'annotation-config'()
    context.'component-scan'('base-package': "org.springframework.security.saml")

    SpringSecurityUtils.registerProvider 'samlAuthenticationProvider'
    SpringSecurityUtils.registerLogoutHandler 'successLogoutHandler'
    SpringSecurityUtils.registerLogoutHandler 'logoutHandler'


    successRedirectHandler(SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler) {
        alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl = conf.saml.alwaysUseAfterLoginUrl ?: false
        defaultTargetUrl = conf.saml.afterLoginUrl
    }

    successLogoutHandler(SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler) {
        defaultTargetUrl = conf.saml.afterLogoutUrl
    }

    samlLogger(SAMLDefaultLogger)

    keyManager(JKSKeyManager,
            conf.saml.keyManager.storeFile, conf.saml.keyManager.storePass, conf.saml.keyManager.passwords, conf.saml.keyManager.defaultKey)

    samlEntryPoint(SAMLEntryPoint) {
        println "Entry point process url is ${conf.saml.loginFormUrl}"
        filterProcessesUrl = conf.saml.loginFormUrl                         // '/saml/login'
        defaultProfileOptions = ref('webProfileOptions')
    }

    webProfileOptions(WebSSOProfileOptions) {
        includeScoping = false
    }

//  metadataFilter(MetadataDisplayFilter) {
//      println "metadataFilter process url: ${conf.saml.metadata.url }"
//      filterProcessesUrl = conf.saml.metadata.url             //'/saml/metadata'
//  }
//
    metadataGenerator(MetadataGenerator) {
        includeDiscoveryExtension = true
    }

    metadataGeneratorFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter, ref('metadataGenerator'))

    log.debug "Defining the default idp metadata provider... "
    def idpResource
    def idpFile = conf.saml.metadata.idp.file

    if(idpFile){
        idpResource = new ClassPathResource(idpFile)
        defaultIdpMetadata(ExtendedMetadataDelegate) { extMetaDataDelegateBean ->
            idpMetadataProvider(FilesystemMetadataProvider) { bean ->
                bean.constructorArgs = [idpResource.getFile()]
                parserPool = ref('parserPool')
            }

            extMetaDataDelegateBean.constructorArgs = [ref('idpMetadataProvider')]

        }
    }

    def spFile = conf.saml.metadata.sp.file
    if (spFile) {
        def spResource = new ClassPathResource(spFile)
        spMetadata(ExtendedMetadataDelegate) { spMetadataBean ->
            spMetadataProvider(FilesystemMetadataProvider) { spMetadataProviderBean ->
                spMetadataProviderBean.constructorArgs = [spResource.getFile()]
                parserPool = ref('parserPool')
            }

            def spDefaults = conf.saml.metadata.sp.defaults
            spMetadataDefaults(ExtendedMetadata) { extMetadata ->
                local = spDefaults.local
                alias = spDefaults.alias
                signingKey = spDefaults.signingKey
                encryptionKey = spDefaults.encryptionKey
                tlsKey = spDefaults.tlsKey
                requireArtifactResolveSigned = spDefaults.requireArtifactResolveSigned
                requireLogoutRequestSigned = spDefaults.requireLogoutRequestSigned
                requireLogoutResponseSigned = spDefaults.requireLogoutResponseSigned
                idpDiscoveryEnabled = spDefaults.idpDiscoveryEnabled
            }

            spMetadataBean.constructorArgs = [ref('spMetadataProvider'), ref('spMetadataDefaults')]
        }
    }

    metadata(CachingMetadataManager,[ref('spMetadata'), ref('defaultIdpMetadata')]){
        hostedSPName = conf.saml.metadata.sp?."alias"
        defaultIDP = conf.saml.metadata.defaultIdp
    }

    samlUserDetailsService(SpringSamlUserDetailsService) {
        grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
        authorityClassName = conf.authority.className
        authorityJoinClassName = conf.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName
        authorityNameField = conf.authority.nameField
        samlAutoCreateActive = conf.saml.autoCreate.active
        samlAutoAssignAuthorities = conf.saml.autoCreate.assignAuthorities
        samlAutoCreateKey = conf.saml.autoCreate.key
        samlUserAttributeMappings = conf.saml.userAttributeMappings
        samlUserGroupAttribute = conf.saml.userGroupAttribute
        samlUserGroupToRoleMapping = conf.saml.userGroupToRoleMapping
        userDomainClassName = conf.userLookup.userDomainClassName
    }

    samlAuthenticationProvider(GrailsSAMLAuthenticationProvider) {
        userDetails = ref('samlUserDetailsService')
        hokConsumer = ref('webSSOprofileConsumer')
    }

    metadataResolver(MetadataCredentialResolver,ref('metadata'),ref('keyManager')) {
        useXmlMetadata = true
    }

    contextProvider(SAMLContextProviderImpl) {
        metadataResolver = ref('metadataResolver')
    }

    samlProcessingFilter(SAMLProcessingFilter) {
        authenticationManager = ref('authenticationManager')
        authenticationSuccessHandler = ref('successRedirectHandler')
        sessionAuthenticationStrategy = ref('sessionFixationProtectionStrategy')
        authenticationFailureHandler = ref('authenticationFailureHandler')
    }

    authenticationFailureHandler(AjaxAwareAuthenticationFailureHandler) {
        redirectStrategy = ref('redirectStrategy')
        defaultFailureUrl = conf.failureHandler.defaultFailureUrl //'/login/authfail?login_error=1'
        useForward = conf.failureHandler.useForward // false
        ajaxAuthenticationFailureUrl = conf.failureHandler.ajaxAuthFailUrl // '/login/authfail?ajax=true'
        exceptionMappings = conf.failureHandler.exceptionMappings // [:]
    }

    redirectStrategy(DefaultRedirectStrategy) {
        contextRelative = conf.redirectStrategy.contextRelative // false
    }

    sessionFixationProtectionStrategy(SessionFixationProtectionStrategy)

    logoutHandler(SecurityContextLogoutHandler) {
        invalidateHttpSession = true
    }

    samlLogoutFilter(SAMLLogoutFilter,
            ref('successLogoutHandler'), ref('logoutHandler'), ref('logoutHandler'))

    samlLogoutProcessingFilter(SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter,
            ref('successLogoutHandler'), ref('logoutHandler'))

    webSSOprofileConsumer(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl){
        responseSkew = conf.saml.responseSkew
    }

    webSSOprofile(WebSSOProfileImpl)

    ecpprofile(WebSSOProfileECPImpl)

    logoutprofile(SingleLogoutProfileImpl)

    postBinding(HTTPPostBinding, ref('parserPool'), ref('velocityEngine'))

    redirectBinding(HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding, ref('parserPool'))

    artifactBinding(HTTPArtifactBinding,
            ref('parserPool'),
            ref('velocityEngine'),
            ref('artifactResolutionProfile')
    )

    artifactResolutionProfile(ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl, ref('httpClient')) {
        processor = ref('soapProcessor')
    }

    httpClient(HttpClient)

    soapProcessor(SAMLProcessorImpl, ref('soapBinding'))

    soapBinding(HTTPSOAP11Binding, ref('parserPool'))

    paosBinding(HTTPPAOS11Binding, ref('parserPool'))

    bootStrap(SAMLBootstrap)

    velocityEngine(VelocityFactory) { bean ->
        bean.factoryMethod = "getEngine"
    }

    parserPool(BasicParserPool)

    securityTagLib(SamlTagLib) {
        springSecurityService = ref('samlSpringSecurityService')
        webExpressionHandler = ref('webExpressionHandler')
        webInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator = ref('webInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator')
    }

    samlSpringSecurityService(SamlSecurityService) {
        config = conf
        authenticationTrustResolver = ref('authenticationTrustResolver')
        grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
        passwordEncoder = ref('passwordEncoder')
        objectDefinitionSource = ref('objectDefinitionSource')
        userDetailsService = ref('userDetailsService')
        userCache = ref('userCache')
    }

    println '...finished configuring Spring Security SAML'
```

I have added my full stacktrace here http://pasted.co/97aa6cb4, please review and let me know if you find the problem
I can provide more details if you want, can anyone help why is this happening? and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the first argument in the JKSKeyManager's constructor which is a org.springframework.core.io.Resource, the implementation that seems to fit best with your config value is a org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.

```
cpResource(ClassPathResource, conf.saml.keyManager.storeFile )

keyManager(JKSKeyManager,
        ref('cpResource'),
        conf.saml.keyManager.storePass,
        conf.saml.keyManager.passwords,
        conf.saml.keyManager.defaultKey)
```

Comment: That Resource issue has been resolved, but now I am facing a null pointer exception, I have updated the question and its title, can you please provide a solution for new issue

Comment: Have you changed resources.groovy to get past initial issue? Can you show latest version.

Comment: I did not changed resources,groovy file, issue was in my config file as I was using `samlKeyManager` instead of `keyManager` I have updated that but now I am facing this issue.

Comment: I have added my full stacktrace here http://pasted.co/97aa6cb4, please review and let me know if you find the problem

Comment: Did you try the code above? It'd be nice to know that specifying the concrete implementation Resource makes a difference or not as there are multiples that take a single String constructor argument.

Comment: yes I tried the above solution and it worked and it produced same error :(